# Why does my SQL query return rows with NULL? It should never return rows with NULL

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a SQL table called AT_Devices with each record representing a piece of hardware.  I have a second table called AT_Event_History which describes "events" that occur for pieces of hardware.  An event can consist of something like the piece of equipment being lost, destroyed, retired, etc.  Each event has a corresponding status code.

I've written some SQL to return the code of the most recent event for each record in AT_Devices.  I have a business rule that if the device has no events on record, the status code should be 0.

I've written my SQL query to return 0 in this case, but for some reason, it is returning NULL.  Why?

```
SELECT atDeviceHistory.StatusCodeNotNull AS StatusCode0  
 FROM dbo.AT_Devices atd LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DeviceID,
     ParentCode,
     (CASE WHEN (StatusCode IS NOT NULL) THEN StatusCode ELSE 0 END) AS  
     StatusCodeNotNull,  
     WhenEntered AS StatusDate
FROM AT_Event_History as A
WHERE A.ParentCode=0 
AND A.WhenEntered >= (SELECT MAX(WhenEntered) 
                      FROM AT_Event_History AS B 
                      WHERE A.DeviceID=B.DeviceID AND ParentCode=0)
 ) atDeviceHistory ON atd.DeviceID=atDeviceHistory.DeviceID
```

Comment: Can you show us some of the source data that is returning null?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something. You are doing a left outer join against a derived table. If table `dbo.AT_Devices` has rows that is not present in the derived table `atDeviceHistory` you will have null values in the resultset.

Comment: Why would you do this: CASE WHEN (StatusCode IS NOT NULL) THEN StatusCode ELSE 0 END insted of this: ISNULL(StatusCode,0)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are doing a `left join`, if there are no matching records a null value will be returned for anything referencing the `atDeviceHistory` columns.  If you do not want to return records with no match, then change this to an `inner join`.  I would also recommend changing your case statement to a `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT DeviceID,
     ParentCode,
     COALESCE(StatusCode ,0) AS StatusCodeNotNull,   
     WhenEntered AS StatusDate
FROM AT_Event_History as A
```

UPDATE:

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(atDeviceHistory.StatusCode,0)  AS StatusCode0  
 FROM dbo.AT_Devices atd LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT DeviceID,
     ParentCode,
     StatusCode  
     WhenEntered AS StatusDate
FROM AT_Event_History as A
WHERE A.ParentCode=0 
AND A.WhenEntered >= (SELECT MAX(WhenEntered) 
                      FROM AT_Event_History AS B 
                      WHERE A.DeviceID=B.DeviceID AND ParentCode=0)
 ) atDeviceHistory ON atd.DeviceID=atDeviceHistory.DeviceID
```

Comment: +1: Excellent point!  In this particular case, I need to have the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` because there are other fields being read in my production code.  But still, I would really like to make my query return a default value of 0 for this column when it would otherwise be NULL.

Comment: Try throwing the COALESCE onto the select at the top level instead of your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Now that [@Abe Miessler has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10640608/297408) the misplaced NULL check in your query, you could actually get rid of the subselect and rewrite the entire query like this:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(h.StatusCode, 0) AS StatusCode0,
  … /* whatever other columns you might need */
FROM dbo.AT_Devices atd
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AT_Event_History h ON atd.DeviceID = h.DeviceID
    AND h.ParentCode = 0
    AND h.WhenEntered = (SELECT MAX(WhenEntered)
                         FROM AT_Event_history
                         WHERE DeviceID = a.DeviceID AND ParentCode = 0)
```