# Why does my SQL syntax show null?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I am little perplexed on why my result of this statement shows null in the Project_ID. I took a look at the below post and tried the `inner join` instead but the result was futile, the same as with the `left join`. I have only two distinct Project_ID. For some odd reason, the `Name` is being stated again with the `Count` added from the previous listings. Why is it doing this and how can I fix this? Please provide your advice.

[Why does my SQL query return rows with NULL? It should never return rows with NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640533/why-does-my-sql-query-return-rows-with-null-it-should-never-return-rows-with-nu)

```
select dp."Name",count(dp."Name") Count,max(to_char(ft."Hours",'9,999')) "Maximum Hours Worked",
max(ft."Salary"::money) "Maximum Salary",
ft."Project_ID"
from facttable ft
left join alldatainput dp on dp."alldatainputpk" = ft."alldatainputfk"
group by rollup(dp."Name",ft."Project_ID")
```

Result:

```
       Name             Count    Maximum Hours Worked  Maximum Salary  Project_ID
Hulk Hogan              157           3,500             $432,995.00     LFC
Hulk Hogan              43            3,499             $550,000.00     PCR
Hulk Hogan              200           3,500             $550,000.00   (null)
Andre the Giant         42            5,300             $870,000.00     PCR
Andre the Giant         42            5,300             $870,000.00   (null)
Bret Hart                5            3,675             $512,000.00     LFC
Bret Hart               10            4,193             $716,510.00     PCR
Bret Hart               15            4,193             $716,510.00   (null)
Winnie the Pooh         561           5,600             $929,654.00     PCR
Winnie the Pooh         561           5,600             $929,654.00   (null)
                        1000          5,600             $929,654.00   (null)
```

Comment: It's from the `rollup` - It's applying your aggregates over each grouping of `Name` and `Project_Id` as a summary.  Thus, you get a total `count` and the `max` records for the group from hours worked and salary.  The final record is a summary of the entire set.

Comment: If I remove the `rollup`, it would not deliver the total for each of the columns for me. What's the most viable way to add a total to all the columns for this statement then?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about postgres syntax to answer how to filter out the sub-groupings.

Comment: No problems @ Siyual. We are all here to learn from each other....

Comment: Your query doesn't produce a column called `Project_Id`, so that query is not producing the specified results.

Comment: It does @ Gordon, `ft."Project_ID"`...PCR or LFC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Grouping Sets](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS)

```
select
    dp.Name,count(dp."Name") Count,
    max(to_char(ft."Hours",'9,999')) "Maximum Hours Worked",
    max(ft."Salary"::money) "Maximum Salary",
    ft."Project_ID"
from
    facttable ft
    left join
    alldatainput dp on dp."alldatainputpk" = ft."alldatainputfk"
group by grouping sets ((dp."Name",ft."Project_ID"), ())
```